# Яндекс Карты: ближайший водоем

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли через существующий API получить ближайший водоем по координатам точки? Видел примеры для кафе, метро, но информации по объектам типа леса, водоемов не нашел

Comment: а какая у вас задача на выходе?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно воспользоваться API Поиска по организациям - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/about-docpage/

В параметре запроса в поле text указываются координаты, а в поле type=geo, что означает поиск по топониму.